# updating SQL table cells from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables that are identical, except that one of them has values in a particular column 'extra_fields' (and the other doesn't have any value in that column).

I would like to grab the data from the populated table and update the other table.

I tried this (but it didn't work):

```
update store_k2_items (extra_fields) select extra_fields from j25_k2_items
```

All help appreciated.

Comment: Read up on Foreign keys for MYSQL as they will keep everything up to date automatically.

Comment: @DenverWilliam Foreign keys don't update things automatically. They're just used as constraints to ensure that you don't refer to nonexistent elements.

Comment: @Barmar, that is completely not true. You can set an Foreign key to update or delete or do nothing if the other table is changed. Read up on it. I use it all the time to remain consistant. It is really hand when you have a item with sub items and you delete the main item and all the subitems in your subitems list delete automatically. TRUST ME, it does this if you use it right!

Comment: I know you can make it propagate deletes, to keep things consistent. I don't think you can make other columns automatically transfer, as the question requests. You could do that with a trigger.

Comment: But it will only update the key itself and not anything else.

Comment: @Barmar, you are right, if he wants to do this to many columns then yes, however, if it is just one column this would work if he is planning on keeping both tables.

Comment: @DenverWilliam Could you post what you're suggesting as an answer?

Comment: There is too much to post on the subject. Google FOREIGN KEYS MYSQL and tutorials. Sorry. I cant write it out ATM.

Comment: The thing is, I've read the MySQL documentation on foreign keys http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html, and I don't see where it says it can do what this question asks about. Foreign keys are just _constraints_. If you can't answer the question, at least give a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key
SET t1.extra_fields = t2.extra_fields
```

In this example, `table2` is the table with extra_fields filled in. This will copy the values to the corresponding rows in `table1`.